# Trouble with png img in html

Tags: html, css, png, transparent

my first days in html/css and my first post on stackoverflow. I have this beginner problem with a png img that I want to include in my html. I have tried with:

html:

```
<div class="transparent">
<img style="background: transparent;" src="img./skypepng.png"
</div>
```

css:

```
.transparent{
background: transparent;
}
```

but I can´t figure it out. Please help.

Thanks in advance. Evidence:

[checkered background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNxaj.jpg)

Comment: May I ask how you created the png file? Because, from the screenshot, it looks more like you took a screenshot of the image from the graphics program instead of properly saving it as png.

Comment: You are right...

Answer (score 0):

Your png must have a transparent background to display the alpha layer

Comment: You are right and I feel so dumb...It´s solve anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Download a transparent Skype image from the internet (make sure no copyright). Link the image in a static folder, and add a link such as this...

```
src="{{url_for('static', filename='skype.png')}}"
```

Where the filename is the name of the file.

Comment: You are right and I feel so dumb...It´s solve anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

some png images just appear to be transparent, when in reality they have the checkered background, which acts like a background. Try opening the png in a image viewer. Check if it's a truly transparent image, or does it show the checkered background.

Also, you insert images like this:

```
<img src="../images/image.png" alt="Image">
```

Comment: You are right and I feel so dumb...It´s solve anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure the image is actually transparent and not just a screenshot of the original transparent image as the name `skypepng.png` makes it seem that way. For the CSS I would try

```
 .transparent{
  background: url("skypepng.png") transparent
}
```

Also if you are not giving any colors for the background, then by default it will be white on most browsers.
Hope this helped!

Comment: You are right and I feel so dumb...It´s solve anyway. Thanks.